# Are low-rank kernel approximations implementing implicit regularization?

Tags: covariance-matrix, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, kernel-smoothing, eigenvalues

Consider a kernel estimation problem as follows. We have functions $f^* \sim GP(0, C^*)$ drawn from a Gaussian process. We want to construct a kernel $K$ that does well in regressing functions drawn from this distribution (over functions). Note that given a data set $X$ from some $p(x) $ distribution, $K, X$ completely determines an estimator $\hat{f}(x_*) = \sum_i \alpha_i K(x_i, x_*)$ for $x_i \in X$ (by the representer theorem). Then we can get a generalization error of $K$ by examining $E_{f^*, X, x_*}[(\hat{f}(x_*)-f^*(x_*)^2]$, and we seek a $K$ that minimizes this. Note that the test point $x_* \sim p(x)$ also.

Then if we observe $y = x_* + \epsilon$ for $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ being noisy, however, and want to construct $K$ to do well on regressing these *noisy* observations, it makes sense to use some form of regularization. Then for larger noises, $\epsilon$, we want more regularization in constructing $\hat{f}$. In particular, if constructed $K$ by taking a low-rank approximation of $C^*$, it would make sense to use a lower-rank approximation the larger the noise is. That is, simply "copying" the eigenspectrum of $C^*$, and dropping some of the smallest eigenvalues based on how large $\sigma^2$ is.

The question is: we know low-rank approximations are used in kernel methods for computational reasons, but can it be that they also implement implicit regularization? What is known about this sort of regularization? Are there results about this, or how it's equivalent to ridge regularization? What sub-field would study this?